# Where to write JavaScript in my android Program

Tags: javascript, android, dictionary

From last 2 weeks I am searching for an answer but not getting a bit of success.
My scenario is, I am using Eclipse for developing Android apps. I want to display route directions (Driving, Walking, Bicycling) between two dynamically entered addresses on Google Maps... I want to make use of Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Services, because of all its  awesome functionalities...
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions

I was suggested by some developers on Stack Overflow and they gave this link http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html#why But this site has code that uses some JavaScripts in the code, if this site is having the correct stuff, where am I supposed to write JavaScript in my eclipse android app because AFAIK code written in eclipse uses only Java framework.. If that site is not a good bet give me some other links that demonstrates with examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to worry about javascript. The MAP_URL (http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles-android-webmap/simple-android-map.html) in WebMapActivity has this javascript in the page.  So Either you can write your own html page with that javascript (hosted on your server) or you can simply load the MAP_URL into your webview without worrying about javascript.

Comment: Thanks bhups, can you tell me which url i should use in order to get route directions..

Comment: You can start off with this example page http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-directions/draggable-directions.html, you can simply load this page in your webview and route direction will be rendered for hardcoded start/end point (in the page JS). You can modify js in the page as well as you JSInterface to make it more generic so that you can pass start/end whenever you want.

Comment: hi can you please tell me how to render start end point in Js/JSInterface Whenever i want... can you describe me with some code written ...plz

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I follow you. On the link provided earlier on SO, I see the Java code:
http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html#why

That actually uses Android SDK support for Google Maps. If you still want to use the Javascript, you will have to go through WebView. I would otherwise recomment the way it is followed here:
http://code.google.com/intl/en/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

This page was linked to the previous link mentioned above and it uses Java not Javascript.

Comment: +1) As far as addressing the maps aspect i'd also suggest the second link @hairyhi has provided.

Comment: no hairyhi if you see that link carefully, there they have used javascript centerAt function in the code...actually centerat function is written in javascript..

Comment: can you please point me to it? I might be able to explain it a little better.

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html#why    in the above link go at the end there is a section "The Map"..look at there..

Comment: oh please ignore my previous comment. I got what you were saying. So, there are 2 approaches to use Google maps. One that is mentioned on the first link is the Javascript approach, and the document mentions that this might be useful in some scenarios where you want to run it via a webserver (your own website link), but otherwise you should go with the Java approach mentioned in my second link. Hope that helps.

Comment: hi but in the second approach also they are loading the url string that string  has the centerAt function name which has been written in java script..

Comment: well the second link is about using MapView, using a library provided by Android. Also you can view an example of the same at this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: I think there's just a miscommunication, when I said second link, I meant second link in my answer post not your question post, i.e., http://code.google.com/intl/en/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

Comment: oh sorry, but using Map View we can only use Geocoder class i think, if you are sure that we can use route directions functionalities also can you plz provide me some api's that gives route directions through Map View

Comment: I am not sure of that. I found one related blog post: http://mobile.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-part-1-get-the-route/

Comment: thanks a lot, let me tell you that this link i have seen before , there they are using javascript V2 using that we can only give the address statically...but i want to use V3 for taking adrress from user dynamically